# Radium doesn't work with React Router IndexLink component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

[Radium](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium) doesn't work with React Router `IndexLink` component. I used the [FAQ's method](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium/tree/master/docs/faq#why-doesnt-radium-work-on-react-routers-link-or-react-bootstraps-button-or-someothercomponent) but that doesn't fix the issue.

Here is my code:

```js
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {IndexLink} from 'react-router';
import {deepPurple500, deepPurple300, grey600} from 'material-ui/styles/colors';
import radium from 'radium';

import {default as rem} from 'helpers/calculateRem';

const DecoratedIndexLink = radium(IndexLink);

/**
 * Link component.
 *
 * @param {Object} style
 * @param {String} to
 * @param {String} label
 * @param {Boolean} secondary
 */
function Link({style, to, label, secondary}) {
  const defaultStyle = {
    textDecoration: 'none',
    color: secondary ? grey600 : deepPurple500,
    borderBottomWidth: rem(1),
    borderBottomStyle: 'solid',
    borderColor: secondary ? grey600 : deepPurple500,
    ':hover': {
      color: deepPurple300
    }
  };

  return <DecoratedIndexLink style={{...style, ...defaultStyle}} to={to}>{label}</DecoratedIndexLink>;
}

Link.prototype.propTypes = {
  style: PropTypes.obj,
  to: PropTypes.string,
  label: PropTypes.string,
  secondary: PropTypes.bool
};

export default radium(Link);
```

I decorate the `export default` with Radium, but nothing change with or without it. I even tried to replace `IndexLink` by a DOM element like `button` and its works, so I guess it's entirely related to custom components.

Any hint on this case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react'; 
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import {deepPurple500, deepPurple300, grey600} from 'material-ui/styles/colors';
import radium from 'radium';

import {default as rem} from 'helpers/calculateRem';

const DecoratedLink = radium(Link);

function Link({style, to, label, secondary) {
  const defaultStyle = {
    textDecoration: 'none',
    color: secondary ? grey600 : deepPurple500,
    borderBottomWidth: rem(1),
    borderBottomStyle: 'solid',
    borderColor: secondary ? grey600 : deepPurple500,
    ':hover': {
      color: deepPurple300
    }
  };

  return (
    <DecoratedLink style={[style, defaultStyle]} to={to} onlyActiveOnIndex>
      {label}
    </DecoratedLink>;
  );
}

Link.prototype.propTypes = {
  style: PropTypes.obj,
  to: PropTypes.string,
  label: PropTypes.string,
  secondary: PropTypes.bool
};

export default radium(Link);
```

As shown in the FAQs, Radium cannot influence the style of custom, non-DOM elements within your react component. This means that decorating your component with Radium at export will have no effects on custom elements such as react-router's `Link` or `IndexLink`.

Radium does provide a workaround that works for many custom elements - wrapping the custom elements in Radium, such as their example: `Link = Radium(Link);`. While this does work for react-router's `Link` element, it does not work for `IndexLink`. This is because IndexLink solely returns a Link element with the prop, onlyActiveOnIndex; Radium is wrapped around IndexLink, but is not wrapped around the Link element that it is returning.

Since wrapping Radium around IndexLink is ineffective, wrap Radium around Link and pass into it the onlyActiveOnIndex prop. `<Link {...props} onlyActiveOnIndex />` should function exactly the same as `<IndexLink {...props} />` and will work when wrapped with Radium.

Documentation on onlyActiveOnIndex: https://github.com/jaredly/react-router-1/blob/6fae746355e2679b12518c798d3ef0e28a5be955/docs/API.md#onlyactiveonindex